# Agregar el mismo post en varias páginas diferentes

Tags: html5, wordpress, php7

tengo una duda con una web que estoy creando con WordPress, la web en sí está relacionado con juegos online, pero para darme a entender un poquito mejor me referiré a lo que estoy haciendo como uno web de receteas, de cualquier clase de recetas.

Ahora bien, tengo lo siguiente:

Tengo una página llamada `Recetas` que explica brevemente los tipos de recetas que manejo y en la parte inferior se muestra una lista de páginas del `Tipo de recetas` como por ejemplo:

`Recetas de carnes`, `recetas de pescado`, `recetas de vegetales`, `recetas de dulces`, etc... y así muchas otras.

Como es de esperarse, al entrar en cada una de esas subpáginas habrá una lista de recetas de esa misma clase, por ejemplo en la subpágina de `Recetas de Carnes` hay una lista de los diferentes tipos de recetas de carnes, pueden ser `Carne en Salsa`, `Carne a la Parrilla`, `Carne con Vegetales`, `Carne con Papas`, `Carne con Carne`, etc y cada una de esas recetas específicas cuenta con una plantilla común a todas las recetas de cualquier tipo donde cada una muestra su información particular.

He aquí una ilustración de lo que he mencionado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, para las recetas quiero hacer un `Custom Post Type` con sus `Custom Post Fields` para agregar todas las recetas en general, pero el problema radica en lo siguiente:

¿Como especifico hacia cual página va cada receta en particular? Es decir, en un caso hipotético estoy agregando una publicación de una receta de un dulce y justo después he agregado otra publicación pero de una receta de carnes y luego otra de algún plato de vegetales, todo a través del mismo `custom post`:

¿Como hago para que las recetas de Dulces se publiquen en la página de `Recetas de Dulces` y la receta de Carnes se publique en la página de `Recetas de Carnes` (y así en lo sucesivo) usando la misma plantilla común para todas las recetas?

Espero haberme dado a entender. Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia es bienvenida. De antemano muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando wordpress mi recomendación es usar el sistema de categorías de wordpress, si estas usando un plugin para crear el post type puedes habilitar las categorías en las configuraciones del plugin, si estas creando el post type con código, solo agrega en taxonomías las categorías como argumento, así: `'taxonomies' => array( 'category'),` esto habilitara las categorías en tus post type, cuando creas el post le asignas una categoría y wordpress te mostrara todos los post que pertenecen a dicha categoría.

Ahora bien, por defecto wordpress usa el archivo, single.php para mostrar las categorías, pero también puedes crear una vista personalizada, creando un archivo con el nombre category-nombre-de-la-categoria.php de esa forma puedes hacer que cierta categoría tenga un diseño diferente a otras.

Te recomiendo indagar mas en el tema para tener una idea mas amplia del mismo.

Una vez tengas tus post y categorías creadas, en tu single solo debes enlistas todas las categorías, y al seleccionar una categoría mostrara todos los post que pertenecen a ella.

Comment: Por favor, corrígeme si me equivoco. Entonces debo agregar las categorías a las publicaciones, ejemplo: Category: Dulces, y creando el archivo category-dulces.php podré ver en él todos los posts que pertenecen a la categoría Dulces? Luego puedo usar esa pagina  category-dulces.php para agregarla a la lista de "Tipos de Recetas" por ejemplo, la cual le mostraria al usuario toda la lista de "Dulces" que hay publicados... Es así?
De verdad un millón de gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder, soy nuevo en wordpress y de verdad esto es muy importante para mi. Nuevamente gracias!

Comment: Es correcto, puedes hacer una lista de todas tus categorías, al ingresar a categoría dulces veras todos los post de dicha categoría.

Si mi respuesta le ayudo agradecería que la votara como aceptada.

Comment: definitivamente tu respuesta fue la clave. En este momento estoy probando todas estas cosas y el resultado es simplemente perfecto, ya estoy manos a la obra con algunas categorías y su personalización. Gracias a usted por tomarse la molestia de responder a mis dudas con una respuesta corta, clara y muy muy precisa. Feliz semana !